# Google Tag Manager not appearing in page source

Tags: html, google-tag-manager, astrojs

I am using Astro framework for building static pages. I got a task to add a google tag right under the opening head tag and the second one immediately after opening the body tag, which I have done (can be seen in code snippet below):

```
---
import Footer from "../components/SharedComponents/Footer.astro";
import Hero, { TypeOfHeroContent } from "../components/SharedComponents/Hero.astro";
import Navbar from "../components/SharedComponents/Navbar.astro";
import { networksAndHero } from "../components/SharedComponents/NetworksAndHeroPreload.astro";

export interface Props {
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  keywords?: string;
  heroContentType?: TypeOfHeroContent;
  navbarColor?: string;
  pageName?: string;
}

const { title, description, keywords, heroContentType, navbarColor, pageName } = Astro.props;
---

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>
      (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({ "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(), event: "gtm.js" });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s),
          dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
        j.async = true;
        j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "GTM-PCP4MNJ");
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="sitemap" href="/sitemap-index.xml" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Inter.var.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin />
    {
      networksAndHero.map((images) => (
        <link rel="preload" as="image" href={images.img} type="image/webp" />
      ))
    }
    <meta
      name="robots"
      content="follow, index, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1, max-image-preview:large"
    />
    <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
    <meta name="description" content={description} />
    <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
    <title>{title}</title>
    <style>
      img {
        aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height);
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: "inter";
        src: url("/fonts/Inter.var.woff2") format("woff2");
        font-display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="bg-fieldblack font-sans">
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript>
      <iframe
        src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PCP4MNJ"
        height="0"
        width="0"
        style="display:none;visibility:hidden"
      >
      </iframe>
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <Navbar navbarColor={navbarColor} />
    {heroContentType && <Hero heroContentType={heroContentType} />}
    <slot />
    <Footer pageName={pageName} />
  </body>
</html>
```

Though for some reason my Google Tag that should be at the top of head section is literally not shown in Inspect Element or Page Source, only the comments around the script tag meanwhile the noscript tag at the top of body section appears to be perfectly fine. Has anyone came across the same thing and know how can I fix it?

[image: Invisible Google Tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `is:inline` directive so Astro will not process and try to optimise the code which downloads Google Tag Manager. You can read more about directives in the Astro Docs - https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#script--style-directives

Example:

```
<script is:inline>
              (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
                w[l] = w[l] || [];
                w[l].push({ "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(), event: "gtm.js" });
                var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                  j = d.createElement(s),
                  dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
                j.async = true;
                j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
                f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
              })(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "GTM-PCP4MNJ");
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done this before

you can see here

I used to put the tag in the header

in which you can explicitly inject that into the header within

```html
<head>
<script>
   The
</script>
</head>
```

I did use it as a component and import it in the baselayout, as I can remove it from some pages
and here is the analytics component

```js
---

---

<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-63B3SL9XYQ"></script>
<script is:inline>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-63B3SL9XYQ');
</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MCK72GRX');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)